# Attraction and repulsion of electron spin ups and electron spin downs

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-spin, electrons, induction

Alright, we know that copper is a diamagnetic material, which has paired electrons. These paired electrons have different spin. I'm specifically interested in what is going on with the electrons in a copper coil, when creating an induced current with a magnet.

1 Question:

"Can you break the bond between an electron spin-up and electron spin-down in a diamagnetic material such as copper - using an external magnetic field?"

2 Question:

"If yes, then could you say that a bar magnet with a north-pole would attract all the spin-ups and repulse all the spin-downs, due to the fact that spin-ups has south pole at the top, and spin-downs has north at the top. This would then create an opposing magnetic field, so that there in the copper would be a north-pole at the top, and a south-pole at the bottom."

3 Question:
"If further yes, could you say that the movement of the electron spin-ups and electron spin-downs is the so called induced current."

4 Question:
"And when the bar magnet is pulled out of the coil, the spin-ups and spin-downs will naturally find each other again, and bind and create a zero-magnetic field."

Statement: If I make experiments with the galvanometer, I can see that the current is going different ways, depending on which pole I use, which in my mind can prove to be a valid proof that the bar magnet is attracting and repulsing at the same time. Either spin ups og spin downs, regarding which pole being used.

5 Question:
"If all this is wrong, and you cannot break the bond between spin-ups and spin-downs, then what exactly is the bar-magnet doing to the electrons?"

Many Regards

Comment: No question 5?...

Comment: My mistake, should be corrected now.

Comment: Copper is diamagnetic, but why are you saying the electrons are paired?  You seem to be implying that the electrons in copper form Cooper pairs, as in conventional superconductors.  While superconductors are diamagnetic as well, there is no reason to believe all diamagnetic materials have Cooper pairing.  In fact, copper does NOT become superconducting, nor are electron-electron interactions appreciable enough to introduce exotic behavior.  The electronic properties are well described by conventional theories of conduction, such as the Drude model or the band theory of solids.